# Remove trailing slash at end of the line if present in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I've got a batch of URLs some with a trailing slash others without. I would like to remove the slash at the end of the URL if it's present. 
I've been trying to do it with notepad++ but so far I couldn't figured it out.

EDIT:
I didn't include examples:

```
www.myurl1.com/folder/document/
www.myurl2.com/folder/document
www.myurl3.com/folder/document.html
www.myurl4.com/folder/document.html/
```

Comment: Replace with Extended, search for /\n and replace with \n

Comment: Can you include an example of what your file could look like? you can change the urls to dummy urls as long as they show what it could potentially be?

Comment: @RomeoNinov this will only work if the url ends with an enter. If it is part of a csv file for example, and has a ; after it or other data it would not work.

Comment: @LPChip, true, but w/o example from OP this the the best we can offer :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov exactly, so thats why we ask for an example, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove a slash followed by any whitespace at the end of a line.

- Search (menu), Replace
- Search mode: Regular Expression
- Find what: `/[[:space:]]*$`
- Replace with: (leave blank)
- Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd> button